# Whats wrong with this java code?

Tags: java, arrays, try-catch, fileinputstream

I want to store a whole line from a txt file into an array i managed to do that but when it comes to searching from the array i can't seem to do that.Here's the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class GrandFinal {


public void readFromFile()throws IOException {
    String[] grand = new String[200];
    Scanner search = new Scanner(System.in);
    String query;


    try
    {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("NRLdata.txt"));

        int i = 0;
        while (reader.hasNext()){
            i++;
            grand[i] = reader.next();



        }

        System.out.println("Search for GrandFinal: ");
        query = search.next();
        for(int j = 0; j <grand.length; j++)
        {
            if(grand[i].equals(query)){
                System.out.println (grand[j]);
            }
        }

    reader.close();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){//Catch exception if any
          System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
          }
    }


}
```

It doesn't display the result

Comment: try using the debugger. you'll love it!

Comment: Formatting is wrong, for one.

Comment: try grand[j] instead of grand[i]

Answer (score 7):

You want

```
   if (grand[j].equals(query)){
       System.out.println (grand[j]);
   }
```

i.e. use the index **j** since that's what you're looping with.

As the commenters have noted, you should investigate your IDE's debugger.

Comment: Its giving me an error:                                                    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at arrayfile.main(arrayfile.java:33)

Comment: @Sujath Mohammed : Because `grand[0]` is null . You are populating the array from index 1 and when you do `grand[0].equals(query)`, it is a NPE.

Comment: nope still the same                                                     [link](http://ideone.com/3T4Fxo)